# Advantage of "bundle exec rails server" over a simple "rails server"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I bought [Crafting Rails Applications](http://pragprog.com/book/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications) this weekend and noticed that the author uses

```
bundle exec rails server
```

to start the development server. What's the advantage of using this command over a simple "rails server"? Is it simply to keep gem dependencies under control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bundle exec` runs the server in the context of the bundle that you have installed... 
`rails s` or `rails server` does almost the same.

But if you are using rvm or something else you might have some special bundles with special versions of the gems.